# facebook iframe application with ruby and the new open graph api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebooker

i am trying to get an iframe facebook application running with ruby. unfortunately the facebooker gem seems to be broken and even the developer of facebooker suggests using the facebooker2 gem and some workarounds.

see http://www.elevatedcode.com/articles/2010/05/12/facebook-iframe-applications-and-the-new-open-graph-api/#extended

is there an existing tutorial on how to use the new open graph api with ruby? or anyone maybe already successfully wrote an application and give me some pointers/examples?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer my own question: i used the excellent gem oauth2 which can be found here: http://github.com/intridea/oauth2